# CDK LayerVersion fromAsset results in S3 NoSuchKey

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cdk

Using AWS-CDK (v1), I'm trying to create a LayerVersion pointing to a zip in my project. When I try to deploy, my stack fails on that LayerVersion resource with the below error:

> Error occurred while GetObject. S3 Error Code: NoSuchKey. S3 Error Message: The specified key does not exist. (Service: AWSLambdaInternal; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterValueException; Request ID: d6b844e9-a377-43ff-a0ce-1b532347ea52; Proxy: null)`

Here's what the code snippet looks like:

```js
    const layer = new LayerVersion(this, 'xxxLayer', {
      code: Code.fromAsset(path.join(__dirname, '../../xxxpath', 'xxx.zip')),
      compatibleRuntimes: [Runtime.JAVA_11],
      description: 'A layer to add xxx support',
    });
    this.function.addLayers(layer);
```

Why is there an S3 error? A zip that's a part of the project is what is being pointed to, it's not pointing to S3 pointing to a resource (which, as I understand, is an option). Can anyone shed some light on the error?

Comment: Are you sure this is related to the layer and not the Lambda Function itself? (This looks like it's correct at first glance)

Comment: Are you deploying with CDK pipelines?

Comment: Oddly, it fails on first attempt and then a subsequent attempt got this to run after deleting resources that didn't get deleted from the rollback...